# stacked d3 bar chart - specify x/y values

Tags: javascript, python, django, d3.js

My data looks something like:

```
var students = [

{'race': 'Black', 'count': 7, 'year': 2004, 'allnames': ['G Brown', 'F Clarkson', 'E Miller', 'R Black', 'R Tasker', 'T Witter', 'W Garde']}, 
{'race': 'White', 'count': 9, 'year': 2004, 'allnames': ['J Finley', 'M Wenk', 'A Booker', 'C Bush', 'D Jackson', 'E Santoro', 'W Rosen', 'P Bamford', 'H Larson']},
{'race': 'Hispanic', 'count': 2, 'year': 2004, 'allnames': ['T Greene', 'R Golden']},
{'race': 'Asian', 'count': 3, 'year': 2004, 'allnames': ['R Natal', 'G Goldsmith']},

{'race': 'Black', 'count': 6, 'year': 2006, 'allnames': ['R Paul', 'A Gaul', 'P Cathay', 'W Kotch', 'J Nutter', 'J Street']}, 
{'race': 'White', 'count': 4, 'year': 2006, 'allnames': ['M Zuckerberg', 'D Chang', 'V Cruz', 'S Spelman']},
{'race': 'Hispanic', 'count': 3, 'year': 2006, 'allnames': ['T Rossen', 'R Russo',  'M Abbed']},
{'race': 'Asian', 'count': 1, 'year': 2006, 'allnames': ['R Lopez']}

//....

]
```

I want year on my x axis & count on my y axis to have a stacked chart.
The documentation here seems clear if x & y values are isolated in their own object but I have other data in my object too.  How do I pass the values I want (just year & count) to the d3 chart?

My plan is to pass the other data to tooltips so I need to keep that in.  Do I need to structure my data that I'm passing in differently or can I work with my dataset as it is?

I'm looking at the d3 stack documentation here:
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout#values

What do I need in place of `d.values` here?

```
var stack = d3.layout.stack()
    .offset("wiggle")
    .values(function(d) { return d.values; });
```

*Note - this is coming from a Python Django query set - hence the additional tags but I don't know how much that matters.*

Thank you!

ALSO - Please see my data is all in one giant array... does d3 require each series to be in its own array?

Answer (score 0):

`d3.layout.stack` is looking for an array of objects to stack, each array representing the datapoints associated with a particular dimension, with the value Y at each X coordinate. In your case you would want to use d3.nest or a similar function to nest your data so that it looks like:

```
 [
  {"race": "Black", values: [
   {year: 2004, "count": 9},
   {year: 2005, "count": 6}
   ]
  },
  {"race": "White", values: [
   {year: 2004, "count": 9},
   {year: 2005, "count": 4}
   ]
  }
 ]
```

But what stack expects is for your objects to have `x` and `y` values, so you can't just nest and create the objects like that, you need to end up with:

```
 [
  {"race": "Black", values: [
   {x: 2004, y: 9},
   {x: 2005, y: 6}
   ]
  },
  {"race": "White", values: [
   {x: 2004, y: 9},
   {x: 2005, y: 4}
   ]
  }
 ]
```

It's one of the more complicated D3 procedures to understand. You can see an example of how to create the formatted data here:

http://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/b4184089c979aeae28bb

Comment: Got it.  Looks like the x value is defined later on, through `stack.x([accessor])`.  For the example in the documentation, though, `values` is an array of objects, not a single value. How does `stack` know which value to get from the object?

Comment: (or maybe I'm on the wrong track entirely... any advice appreciated!)

Comment: I'm sorry, I completely mixed up stack with a different layout. You're right, values is an array. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Updated answer, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: OK. I had a feeling I'd have to restructure my data set.  Does d3 stack allow any other data to appear in the dataset? Like in my example, I still need to pass `names` in so that I can use them in tooltips. I don't see where I'd put anything else in this data structure since a set of names goes  with each x,y pair.

Comment: You can create anything along with the x,y attributes. You can even recapitulate the data used for your xy if it makes things more convenient: So {x: 2004, y:9, year: 2004, count: 9, names: ["bob","sally","sunil"], otherData: 99} will not cause problems.